# How to connect a .NET API to a SQL Server database both in the same Kubernetes cluster?

Tags: sql-server, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I have a SQL Server running in a pod and an API running in another pod in the same cluster deployed with helm.

I'm able to connect to the database with a port forward and I created a user using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio.

I point out that it's for a development environment and all is ok in production (production databases are outside the cluster).

When my API is deployed, this error is thrown in his pod :

> An error occurred seeding the DB.
> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible.

And

> An error occurred using the connection to database 'dbdev' on server '127.0.0.1,1433'.

I wonder which connection strings to put in order to connect to the database because with that connections strings, it doesn't work :

```
"Server=tcp:127.0.0.1,1433;Initial Catalog=dbdev;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=xxxxxx;Password=xxxpasswordxxx;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=True;Connection Timeout=30;"
```

If it's a problem of connection strings, isn't localhost point inside my cluster ? or am I out of step.

Comment: Not really programming related. Maybe belongs on https://devops.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This *is* programming related, and there are a lot of duplicate or similar questions - you need to ensure the correct ports are open, and the services can connect to each other. If you really want to connect using `127.0.0.1` you need to ensure that the SQL Server service is published on that port. The important code is the cluster configuration

Comment: Thx for the answer Panagiotis, my SQL Server service is published on port 1433 in my cluster, im sure because i can port forward from my machine to the server. I wonder about the IP address because the API pod and the SQL pod is inside the cluster

Answer (score 0):

Ok i found out my problem, i dont have to put IP address in my connection strings but the name of the service in the cluster.

```
"Server=service-name-in-cluster,1433;Initial Catalog=dbdev;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=xxxxxx;Password=xxxpassxxxx;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=True;Connection Timeout=30;"
```